# In-app billing, buying all locked modules at once

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am building an app, consisting of different modules. I want some of them to be free, whereas some others - paid. The payment is done once - you pay and all of the items are unlocked. While building, I am following this tutorial [In-app-billing](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial). However, here the all of the methods are implemented for one item only. How can this be changed and the buying/ordering to affect all of them? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`Promotional Codes`](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6321495?hl=en).

You can create Promo Codes on the Play Console under `Your App -> User Acquisition -> Promotion`.